# Normalize using a given NumPy array (From Python To C#)

Tags: c#, python, arrays, numpy, normalize

I'm trying to convert some Python code into C#, but the difference in code implementation is preventing me from roaching my goal.

I tried creating different arrays and different functions to normalize a C# float array using another array.

Code in Python:

```
mean_vec = np.array([102.9801, 115.9465, 122.7717])
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
     image[i, :, :] = image[i, :, :] - mean_vec[i]
```

Code I tried in C#:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(newBitmap);
Mat newMat = image.Mat;
float[] array = new float[(int)newMat.Total];
newMat.CopyTo(array);
float[] mean_vector = new float[] { 102.9801f, 115.9465f, 122.7717f };

for(int i=0; i<bitmapWidth; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        array[i] = array[i] - mean_vector[j];
}
```

I am getting the following error

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"

Comment: How are you setting the `bitmapWidth` var? As a person with 0 knowledge in Python code, could you put the expected output?

Comment: @ganchito55 It's my image size.
Anyway, I found a way to do the calculation, but the normalization is definitely wrong.
I edited the post with the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < newBitmap.Height; j++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < newBitmap.Width; i++)
                        {
                            floatArray[k, j, i] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(image.Data[j, i, k]) - mean_vec[k];
                        }
                    }
                }
```